# Determine the amount of memory being allocated in a line of code

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, performance-testing, jmx

I'm relatively new to performance testing, and am trying to determine how much memory is being allocated per line of code.  I tried applying the [MemoryMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html) to the problem, but I'm getting nonsense results.

I'm taking a snapshot of the heap usage before the line of code, then I'm taking a snapshot after the line of code, and finally I'm storing the difference if the amount of heap usage increased (assuming that the garbage collector ran if it decreased); the `getSnapshot()` method is run from my test code and is used to reset the counters and print the results.  However, this test is telling me that we're allocating over 20 mb per line, even on lines that don't do any allocation.  If I take the median instead of the mean then I still get nonsense telling me that we're allocating 47 mb per line.

How do I determine how much memory is being allocated in a line of code, and/or what am I doing wrong with my use of the `MemoryMXBean`?

```
private static final MemoryMXBean memBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();

private static final Map<Line, Tuple> lineMap;

static {
  Map<Line, Tuple> map = new EnumMap<Line, Tuple>(Line.class);
  for(Line line : Line.values()) {
    map.put(line, new Tuple());
  }
  lineMap = map;
}

public enum Line {
  line01,
  line02,
  line03,
  ...
}

public static Map<String, Long> getSnapshot() {
  Map<String, Long> returnVal = new HashMap<>();
  for(Map.Entry<Line, Tuple> entry : lineMap.entrySet()) {
    if(entry.getValue().count.get() > 0) {
      returnVal.put(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().memory.getAndSet(0) / entry.getValue().count.getAndSet(0));
    } else {
      entry.getValue().memory.set(0);
    }
  }
  return returnVal;
}

private static class Tuple {
  public final AtomicLong memory = new AtomicLong();
  public final AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong();
}

private static void update(Line line, long value) {
  long finish = memBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed();

  // ignore if the gc ran
  if(finish > value) {
    Tuple tuple = lineMap.get(line);
    tuple.memory.addAndGet(finish - value);
    tuple.count.incrementAndGet();
  }
}

public void codeIamTesting {
  long start = memBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed();
  // line1
  update(Line.line01, start);
}
```

Comment: JVM memory management is way too complex for anything like that. Memory is allocated from pools and memory is not released until a Garbage Collection runs. Trying to do it line-by-line makes no sense in a JVM context. Google [`java memory model`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+memory+model) if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I disable the thread-local allocation buffer (command line argument `-XX:-UseTLAB`) I get sane results - the `memBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed()` call adds some overhead to the results, but it's easy enough to determine what this overhead is (240 bytes in my case) and subtract it from the data.  It appears that when using `-XX:+UseTLAB` (which is the default) the `getUsed()` snapshot only changes when a new buffer is allocated, resulting in most allocations appearing to use zero bytes of heap while a few allocations use several megabytes of heap.  I also used `-XX:+UseParallelGC` to reduce the amount of jitter that I would have gotten with `-XX:+UseG1GC`